# How to use abstract names of unix domain sockets with fcgi in Perl in Linux?

Tags: linux, perl, sockets, fastcgi, unix-socket

In Linux, in Perl, using the FCGI module, using the Open Socket function, is it possible to create an unix domain sockets using abstract names?

I tried to create a socket starting with a null character `\0wibble \zwibble \x{0}wibble` and it didn't work!

It worked only using pathname, as described in unix(7):

```
$socket = FCGI::OpenSocket( "/tmp/wibble", 10 );
```

Thank you!

Comment: +1 for reminding me of the abstract socket namespace!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implementation underlying FCGI::OpenSocket() doesn't support it.

That call ultimately calls a C function `int OS_CreateLocalIpcFd(const char *bindPath, int backlog)`.  You can immediately infer that the `bindPath` argument is understood as a NUL-terminated, rather than a NUL-prefixed, string.

If you could supply your own socket to FCGI.pm, you might have a chance at making this work.

Comment: I think I will need to move from FCGI to uWSGI for using Abstract Socket Namespace!

Comment: Hi! I think we also have another alternative... Instead of moving from FGCI to uWSGI, I could also try to chroot twice (nested chroot)... This way the pathname is out of second jail, but it is inside the first... But I didnt tested if this can be exploited easily... I am sure the second jail can be exited, but i neet to research escaping from the first jail...

Comment: Hi again! Ive discovered that using socat I can relay between pathname or abstract namespace named sockets! This way I can relay from the jail to an abstract socket! thank you @pilcrow!